# How to play .mov file in Android devices using default player?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, avcapturesession

I have been working on an iOS application, in my application I have recorded .mov file using AVCaptureSession, however when I tried to play in any Android devices it is not supporting in their default player. What should I do now, Do I need to record only mp4 type file for Android, Or is there any way to play .mov file itself in Android using their default player?

thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

.MOV files are not a standard video format supported by Android. Depending on what Android versions you're targeting, you'll need to change your format most likely to .mp4 (H.263).

If you can't change the way you are encoding the video recorded in iOS, then maybe you can do a conversion on your server-side from .mov to .mp4, before sending it to Android. (Assuming you have a server-side)

Comment: Sorry but... `.mp4 (H263)`?